# synchronization outside a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am curious what would happen if the code looks like something below. Does that mean every Object in every created thread is synchronized?

```
public synchronized void go() {
    try {
        while(true) {
            //waiting for a new connection
            new Thread(client).start(); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You are **never** outside a thread.

Comment: Does this compile? Where is the IOException coming from? How is `1` a boolean expression?

Comment: Note also that `while (1)` will not compile.  Not in Java at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean every action in every created thread is synchronized?

No.  The `start` method on the new thread returns immediately after launching the new thread.  Then the calling thread exits the synchronized method, so the synchronization lock is released.

**EDIT**: I see you have edited the question to add a `while (1)` loop.  I assume you meant `while (true)` BTW.  This changes my explanation in that the calling thread never leaves the synchronized method.  But the answer is still no.  As Thilo points out in a comment below, the new thread has no relation to that lock.

The calling thread owns the lock created by the synchronized block.  As long as that thread is executing code **within the scope of that block**, it will retain the lock and thus no other thread may enter the block.  In your example, a new thread object is created and the `start` method is called.  This method starts the execution of the thread by calling it's `run` method which executes in the new thread context.  Because it is a new thread context, it is considered to be **outside the scope of the synchronized block** of the calling thread.  Thus the new thread is not blocked, nor does the new thread contain any synchronized code blocks by default.

Comment: And even if it did not leave the method but loop forever while holding on to the lock, the spawned thread has no relation to that lock.

Comment: Actually, in the updated question it does just that (probably runs out of memory before anything else...)

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for your reply. Could you please give me any reference to support this idea "even if it did not leave the method but loop forever while holding on to the lock, the spawned thread has no relation to that lock"? Why the newly created thread is not bound by that lock?

Comment: What does it mean to be "bound by a lock"?

Comment: I added one final paragraph to hopefully clarify this.  @HuangJie - If you want to learn more about this, I suggest you read the Oracle documentation on Java synchronization: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html.

Answer (score 0):

If the method is synchronous call, actions will be synchronized. If the method is asynchronous call, actions will not be synchronized.

In above case, start method is asynchronous, actions will not be synchronized.

Comment: There is no such thing as an asynchronous method call in Java.

Comment: How can that possibly affect the operation of the `synchronized` keyword? Your answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: Assume multiple threads (assume x threads for better understanding) are executing above block of code, these x threads create multiple threads (y threads) one after another. Once the thread executed the block, the synchronized lock will be released.  As synchronized lock is released, these y threads actions won't be synchronized.